# Parsing a list with hyphens including and extra hyphen at the end

Tags: python

I have a function that takes elements in a list and adds a hyphen between them and it works fine, the issue is when I want to add `[" ", " ", " "]` as a list it outputs `------` but it should have outputted `- - -` because there are 3 elements in the list. I can't figure out how to fix this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
def printList(myList):

    str1 = ' '.join(map(str,myList))
    
    for i in range(0, len(str1), 1):
        if (str1[i] == ' '):
            str1 = str1.replace(str1[i], '-')
    print(str1 + "-")
printList([" ", " ", " "])
```

Comment: Why not just '-'.join(myList)?

Comment: Also, as an aside `for i in range(0, len(str1), 1):` 1 is the default value and not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `join()` as this is exactly what it is designed for.

```
'-'.join([" ", " ", " "])
#' - - '
```

If you also want to add `-` to the end, just add it to the output `string`

```
'-'.join([" ", " ", " "]) + '- '
#' - - - '
```

For integer based lists, `map` your elements to `str()`

```
'-'.join(map(str, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
#'1-2-3-4-5'
```

Comment: but the won't work for int lists i.e ```printList([1,2,3,4])```@PacketLoss

Comment: @anon10023108 I have added a section to the answer for integer based lists.